# Can we pass url parameters in form action attribute in Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a simple form.

```
<form action='temp1.cfm?categoryid=4' method="get">
 <input type="text" name="fname">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In the action page I am only getting "fname" in FORM scope but i am not getting the category ID in the URL scope.
Why I am not getting the value of categoryID in ColdFusion?

Comment: fname will be passed as part of the form data. category_id will be sent in the request headers so they are accessed different ways.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can i access categoryid /

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to make categoryid a hidden form field so that you only have one scope to deal with when you submit the form.

Comment: According to your code, both variables should be in the URL scope since you are using `method="get"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your action page, do this -

```
<cfoutput>#URL.categoryId#</cfoutput><br/>
<cfoutput>#FORM.fname#</cfoutput>
```

this will output the values you need.

In CFML -

The GET request values can be accessed via the URL scope and POST will be via the FORM scope. In you case, you are doing a POST but with some values in the URL too. So, access the form values using FORM scope and the url values via URL scope.

Comment: No I am not getting the categoryid in URL scope.

Comment: Cant be!! 
Can you dump your URL and FORM scopes to see what are you receiving on the POST?

Comment: Thanks , its working . But when i use dynamic variable like `<form action='temp1.cfm?categoryid=#a#' method="post">` , it is not replacing the value of a.

Comment: do you have a <cfoutput> around the #a# ?

Comment: According to the code posted above, all variables should be in URL scope as he is using `method="get"`